# Is there any other ways to pass array each elements into the function?

Tags: javascript

I have an array

```
var arr = ['vetri', 30, 'male'];
```

I have to pass this array to one function namely

```
updatecall(name, age, gender){
  // ...
}
```

I call it with:

```
updatecall(arr[0],arr[1],arr[2]):
```

My question is Is there any other way to achieve this in JavaScript.? Help me.

Comment: If you can change the function's parameter, you could change it to: `function updatecall([name, age, gender]){}` and pass the array directly to array like this: `updatecall(arr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Robin Zigmond stated there is an ES6 spread operator, but since you are using var to declare variables, I would assume that you are using the ES5 syntax. There is an equivalent to the spread operator in ES5:

**ES5**

```
updatecall.apply(null, arr)
```

**ES6**

```
updatecall(...arr)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the ES6 spread syntax:

```
updatecall(...arr)
```